# get PDF from web service consumed using json in a jquerymobile + phonegap app

Tags: c#, json, pdf

I have two applications, one in C# and the other using **jquery mobile, phonegap and consuming web services**; this is the method that I use in the C# one to export some data to PDF:

```
    public void exportToPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = Classes.DbManagement.getConnection();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand objCmd = null;
        String sql = "";
        String fileName = "";

        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();

        sql = "SELECT userId " +
                "FROM isProductReport"'";
        objCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(objCmd);

        ds1.EnforceConstraints = false;
        da.Fill(ds1, "isProductReport");

        cr1.SetDataSource(ds1);

        fileName = "reporte de inventario " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hmmtt");
        cr1.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, fileName);
    }
```

It works great in the C# app and it allows me to save the report, I want to use the same method in a web service call, that I would consume using json in the following way:

```
        function exportToPDF()
        {   
            var userIdValue = $("#username").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "http://localhost/Service1.svc/exportToPDF",
                data: JSON.stringify({ userId: userIdValue }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data){                                                                               
                },
                error: function(result){
                    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.StatusText); 
                }
            });                     
        }
```

But obviously, I'm not getting anything, at this point, I don't know how to proceed in order to be able to save the PDF, I would appreciate some guidance, thanks a lot!

EDIT:

This is the Operation contract declaration:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
    [OperationContract]
    void exportToPDF();
```

In case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to consume JSON if PDF is not a JSON file at all?

As it is a file, you can easily open this URL and browser will start downloading itself:

```
window.open('http://localhost/Service1.svc/exportToPDF'); 
// or
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Service1.svc/exportToPDF';
```

However, your method is using POST-method. You need to make it a GET-method to access it this way. As you are using WCF, add `WebGetAttribute` to a method in your `Service1.svc`.

```
[WebGet]
public void exportToPDF()
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I get a **"method not allowed"** message. I was reading that, if I could return the report as a byte array, I could use that to re-create the report and send it to the browser, do you know something about that? thanks

Comment: @saman0suke Your C# code already created a report. Why do you want to transform it to byte array and back? **"Method not allowed"** means that you are trying to access it in `GET`-context while it is a `POST`-method. Read answer update.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to GET, however I don't know how to put the [HttpGet] above the method declaration, it's unrecognized in Visual Studio,  without that declaration, what I'm getting is Chrome and Firefox cancelling the download of the report, why is that happening?

Comment: @saman0suke Sorry about confusing. `HttpGet` stands for ASP.NET, use `WebGet` in a WCF service. However, that's the same as `[WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]` which you already used.

Comment: thanks for that, the browsers does not allow me to download the files, I'm getting **unknown network error**, however, my goal is to use it in a phonegap + jquerymobile app, and window.open does not seem to work on the phone, I should have to point that in the question.